# codeigniter if data doesn't work

Tags: json, codeigniter, datatables

---

I use ignited datatables,when `add_coloumn` doesnt work if value

my controller `add_coloumn`

`$this->datatables->add_column('acces', "$1", $this->custom_value('acces'));`

my callback function

```
public function custom_value($val){
    // value a
        if ($val === 'a') {
            return 'Sending By Admin';
        } 
        else{
            return 'Sending By member';
        }
    }
```

successful but the value is always on `Sending By member`

I tried in the datatables column render

script

```
'columns': [
{"data": "acces",                   
    "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        if(data === 'a'){
            return 'Sending By Admin';
        }
        else{
            return 'Sending By Member';
        }
    }
}
]
```

successful but the value is always on `Sending By member` too

in my database table there are 3 value `acces` 1=m,2=a

Comment: what is the value of $val?

Comment: you are really going to have to make this easy to understand for us. what do you expect $val to be? what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: are you getting the val (check by echoing) that you expect? maybe the try `==` instead of `===`.